# How do I resolve this warning from react, when my useEffect hook is triggered after a react-apollo mutation?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, react-hooks

I have a list of "cards" in my UI where only one card can be expanded at any given time. This list has a `react-apollo` query which watches a list of jobs and returns a prop marking the next uncompleted job (`nextJobId`). This prop is tracked by the `useEffect` hook, which updates the expanded card when the `nextJobId` prop updates.

Inside each card is a button that fires off a `react-apollo` mutation, which updates the DB (setting `job.done` to true), which in turn updates the `nextJobId` prop. As soon as this happens, the card containing the button that was just clicked is collapsed, destroying the button.

This seems to be triggering the following error:

```
react-dom.development.js?61bb:507 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the `componentWillUnmount` method.
```

I believe what is happening is the apollo cache is being updated before the mutation finishes (if I add an `onCompleted` function to the `Mutation` component it's never fired).

Here is the hook:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  client.writeData({
    data: {
      openVisitId: nextJobId
    }
  })
}, [nextJobId])
```

And here is the mutation:

```
mutation FinishJob($visitId: ID!) {
  updateJobInstance(data: { done: true }, where: { id: $visitId }) {
    done
    id
  }
}
```

So far I've worked out two ways to solve this:

1) Add `setTimeout` to the hook:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    client.writeData({
      data: {
        liveVisitId: nextJobId,
        openVisitId: nextJobId
      }
    })
  })
}, [nextJobId])
```

No idea why this works.

2) Remove `done` from the mutation (which bypasses a direct cache update I believe), and use `refetchQueries` to refetch the main list again:

```
mutation FinishJob($visitId: ID!) {
  updateJobInstance(data: { done: true }, where: { id: $visitId }) {
    id
  }
}
```

```
<Mutation mutation={FinishJob} refetchQueries={['CardList']}>...</Mutation>
```

This leads me to think that somehow the cache is being optimistically updated, which is resulting in the clicked button being destroyed before the mutation actually finishes. Is this the case? And if so, is there any way to tell `react-apollo` not to update the cache until the mutation has actually finished?

Comment: Ok adding `ignoreResults` to the `<Mutation />` component seems to solve this issue (see https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations#api).

I won't mark it answered just yet in case there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

What this warning is saying is that you're trying to update the state of an unmounted component. E.x you are waiting for your request to be completed and then to add data to the state, but the request is taking so long, and you are navigating to another page. But the request still is being completed, so after it is completed cant add its data to the state.

So in order to prevent it, its good to use `_isMounted`.

```
function SomeName(){
    const _isMounted = false;

    useEffect(() => {
        _isMounted = true; //this is equivalent of componentDidMoun()
        return () => {
            _isMounted = false; //this is equivalent of componentWillUnmount()
        }
    }, [])
}
```

and now every time you need to update your state you check if it's mounted, in order to update the state

```
if(_isMounted)
{
    this.setState({
        //your data
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense! It seems to be more to do with the `react-apollo` `Mutation` component on the child, rather than the hook on the parent - the child with the mutation was being destroyed before completing (I assume it's using state under the hood).